# Saga Setup, fetch is not executed

Tags: redux, redux-saga, saga

I have the following setup for my saga:

In **saga.js**

```
import { put, call } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { takeLatest } from "redux-saga";
import { SET_BASE_CURRENCY, SET_CURRENCY_REPONSE } from "./duck";
function* fetchCurrencyExchangeRate() {
  const response = yield call(
    fetch,
    "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=USD"
  );
  const data = yield call([response, "json"]);
  // const json = yield fetch(
  //   "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=USD"
  // ).then(response => response.json());
  yield put({ type: SET_CURRENCY_REPONSE, json: data });
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield takeLatest([SET_BASE_CURRENCY], fetchCurrencyExchangeRate);
}
```

In **duck.js**

```
import { defineAction } from "redux-define";
import { createAction, handleActions } from "redux-actions";

export const initialState = {
  exchangeRate: 3.06,
  baseCurrency: "SGD",
  exchangeCurrency: "MYR",
  amountToConvert: 0.0,
  currencyResponse: ""
};

//Action-types
export const SET_EXCHANGE_RATE = defineAction("SET_EXCHANGE_RATE");
export const SET_BASE_CURRENCY = defineAction("SET_BASE_CURRENCY");
export const SET_EXCHANGE_CURRENCY = defineAction("SET_EXCHANGE_CURRENCY");
export const SET_AMOUNT_TO_CONVERT = defineAction("SET_AMOUNT_TO_CONVERT");
export const SET_CURRENCY_REPONSE = defineAction("SET_CURRENCY_REPONSE");

//Action-creators
export const setExchangeRate = createAction(
  SET_EXCHANGE_RATE,
  params => params
);
export const setExchangeCurrency = createAction(
  SET_EXCHANGE_CURRENCY,
  params => params
);
export const setBaseCurrency = createAction(
  SET_BASE_CURRENCY,
  params => params
);
export const setAmountToConvert = createAction(
  SET_BASE_CURRENCY,
  params => params
);
export const setCurrencyResponse = createAction(
  SET_CURRENCY_REPONSE,
  params => params
);

//reducer
const reducer = handleActions(
  {
    [setExchangeRate]: (state, { payload }) => ({
      ...state,
      exchangeRate: payload
    }),
    [setExchangeCurrency]: (state, { payload }) => ({
      ...state,
      exchangeCurrency: payload
    }),
    [setBaseCurrency]: (state, { payload }) => ({
      ...state,
      baseCurrency: payload
    }),
    [setAmountToConvert]: (state, { payload }) => ({
      ...state,
      amountToConvert: payload
    }),
    [setCurrencyResponse]: (state, { payload }) => ({
      ...state,
      currencyResponse: payload
    })
  },
  initialState
);
export default reducer;

//Selector
export const selectExhangeRate = state => state.reducer.exchangeRate;
export const selectExchangeCurrency = state => state.reducer.exchangeCurrency;
export const selectBaseCurrency = state => state.reducer.baseCurrency;
export const selectAmountToConvert = state => state.reducer.amountToConvert;
```

In **index.js** where the saga is setup

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import ReduxThunk from "redux-thunk";
import reducers from "./configureStore/reducers";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import App from "./App";
import rootSaga from "./configureStore/saga";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const middlewares = [ReduxThunk];
const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares),
    applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware),
    window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
  )
);

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
);
```

However, for some reason, I can't get the `call` function or the `fetch` function to work. I wanted it to trigger the api call when `SET_BASE_CURRENCY` action is triggered. Is there a problem with my setup or is it the way I am calling saga is wrong? Full code is inside this sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/todoapp-with-redux-and-normalized-store-jkp8z

Comment: I really suggest to use some newer resources to base your code on. E.g. you need to import `takeLatest` from 'redux-saga/effects'. Also the redux-define library has been last updated in 2017 and it seems to introduce more complexity than it helps. Right now you are using it wrong since your dispatched action types are not strings but objects.

Comment: Okay, I'll look into this

Comment: Have a look at https://redux-toolkit.js.org/ it's from the maintainers of redux lib.